# Refresh a PHP include using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP include file which contains a lot of user actions i.e. login, logout, toolbars, buttons etc. This file is the same across the entire site hence the include. Inside the include I have jQuery scripts which call other files to validate a user login, log them out, user menus etc. This include is the entire header of the site.

Now I want to reload this include after say a user logs into the site but I do not want to reload the entire page and they could be performing action which I dont want them to lose or I dont want them to be stored as cookies/sessions.

There is a container div (#dynamicHeader for for example) which holds the include.

I have tried the .load() from within the include but that does nothing. I know the content is being replaced correctly as I have tried .html("logged in") and the container div displays this. Does anyone know a way to reload the include from within the include?

Many thanks

Comment: If one PHP script does `include` other file, then they are both parsed on the server and are not being transmitted to the browser. jQuery will receive only HTML. You can send new request from jQuery which would then trigger PHP script which would include your file again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.get() [Documentation Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  You would call the page to be included here and set the html of #dynamicHeader to the returned html in the callback.